# How could i pass List<T> by reference into a class from other class? dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have several files and
i want to pass 'messages' to 'floatingActionButton: ComposeButton(messages)' by reference  and add new message from form.
but my constructor in ComposeButton doesn't work.
In ComposeButton message == null,

Could you gyus advice me what i need to do?

[Here all code](https://github.com/gnuvse/email_client/tree/main/lib)

MessageList.dart

```
import 'package:email_clinet/ComposeButton.dart';
import 'package:email_clinet/Message.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'MesageDeatail.dart';

class MessagesList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;
  const MessagesList({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MessagesListState();
}

class _MessagesListState extends State<MessagesList> {
  Future<List<Message>> future;
  List<Message> messages = [];

  initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetch();
  }

  void fetch() async {
    future = Message.browse();
    messages = await future;
    print(messages.length);
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.refresh_sharp),
              onPressed: () async {
                var _messages = await Message.browse();
                setState(() {
                  messages = _messages;
                });
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: future,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
            case ConnectionState.active:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            case ConnectionState.done:
              if (snapshot.hasError)
                return Text("There was an error: ${snapshot.error}");
              var messages = snapshot.data;
              return ListView.separated(
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                itemCount: messages.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  Message message = messages[index];

                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(message.subject),
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                      child: Text("PJ"),
                      backgroundColor: Colors.red[500],
                      foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      message.body,
                      maxLines: 2,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                              MessageDeatail(message.subject, message.body),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },
              );
          }
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButton: ComposeButton(messages),
    );
  }
}
```

ComposeButton.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'Message.dart';
import 'MessageCompose.dart';

class ComposeButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Message> messages;
  ComposeButton(this.messages);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FloatingActionButton(
      child: Icon(Icons.add),
      onPressed: () async {
        Message message = await Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => MessageCompose(),
          ),
        );

        if (message != null) {
          print(messages.length);
          messages.add(message);
          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(
                "Your message has been sent",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[I watch a tutorial, and there code works](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VaWobMmVOWQ&list=PLhXZp00uXBk5TSY6YOdmpzp1yG3QbFvrN&index=12&ab_channel=ZaisteProgramming)

ps. i am sorry for my english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your ComposeButton(messages) runs before messages are fetched. Body of scaffold is initialized as FutureBuilder (which goes async) and then ComposeButton(messages) runs. But future is still not completed so 'messages' is still an empty list.
If I am right then answer to your trouble is in top comment of tutorial you posted.

Comment: Yeah, you right it help to me. Thank you
But know i have another issue - how could i update itemCount in ListView?